# SQL UNION statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I got the following query:

```
SELECT
        ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr AS Dossiernummer,
        SUM(ep_102.id_fhmbdlv) AS Kosten

    FROM ep_101

    INNER JOIN et_101 ON ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr = et_101.cd_hfdmapnr
    INNER JOIN ep_102 ON ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr = ep_102.cd_hfdmapnr

    WHERE ep_101.cd_mapkverw = 0 
    AND ep_102.cd_bkcode = '000010' 
    AND et_101.opdrachtgever1 = '05354605'

    GROUP BY ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr

    UNION

    SELECT
        ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr AS Dossiernummer,
        SUM(ep_102.id_fhmbdlv) AS GriffieKosten

    FROM ep_101

    INNER JOIN et_101 ON ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr = et_101.cd_hfdmapnr
    INNER JOIN ep_102 ON ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr = ep_102.cd_hfdmapnr

    WHERE ep_101.cd_mapkverw = 0 
    AND ep_102.cd_bkcode = '000020' 
    AND et_101.opdrachtgever1 = '05354605'

    GROUP BY ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr
```

Though the results only give back Dossiernummer & Kosten how can I recreate it so that "Griffiekosten" is also shown? Cause I am out of ideas....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're really need to show it in two columns:

```
SELECT
    ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr AS Dossiernummer,
    SUM(case when ep_102.cd_bkcode = '000010' then ep_102.id_fhmbdlv else 0 end) AS Kosten,
    SUM(case when ep_102.cd_bkcode = '000020' then ep_102.id_fhmbdlv else 0 end) AS GriffieKosten
FROM ep_101
    INNER JOIN et_101 ON ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr = et_101.cd_hfdmapnr
    INNER JOIN ep_102 ON ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr = ep_102.cd_hfdmapnr
WHERE ep_101.cd_mapkverw = 0 
    AND ep_102.cd_bkcode in ('000010', '000020')
    AND et_101.opdrachtgever1 = '05354605'
GROUP BY ep_101.cd_hfdmapnr
```

Comment: fix then your `group by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

They are shown!
When you use UNION the column names are according to the first names in the UNION, in this case: Dossiernummer & Kosten.

Just a small question, are you sure you want to use UNION? Are Kosten and Griffiekosten the same? If not then UNION is the wrong way to go.

Assuming they're different types of values but you want the results to show both per each Dossiernummer, then you're looking at a JOIN (on the Dossiernummer).

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Isnull(T1.DOSSIERNUMMER, T2.DOSSIERNUMMER) AS Dossiernummer, 
       T1.KOSTEN, 
       T2.GRIFFIEKOSTEN 
FROM   (SELECT EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR     AS Dossiernummer, 
               Sum(EP_102.ID_FHMBDLV) AS Kosten 
        FROM   EP_101 
               INNER JOIN ET_101 
                       ON EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR = ET_101.CD_HFDMAPNR 
               INNER JOIN EP_102 
                       ON EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR = EP_102.CD_HFDMAPNR 
        WHERE  EP_101.CD_MAPKVERW = 0 
               AND EP_102.CD_BKCODE = '000010' 
               AND ET_101.OPDRACHTGEVER1 = '05354605' 
        GROUP  BY EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR)T1 
       FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR     AS Dossiernummer, 
                               Sum(EP_102.ID_FHMBDLV) AS GriffieKosten 
                        FROM   EP_101 
                               INNER JOIN ET_101 
                                       ON EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR = 
                                          ET_101.CD_HFDMAPNR 
                               INNER JOIN EP_102 
                                       ON EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR = 
                                          EP_102.CD_HFDMAPNR 
                        WHERE  EP_101.CD_MAPKVERW = 0 
                               AND EP_102.CD_BKCODE = '000020' 
                               AND ET_101.OPDRACHTGEVER1 = '05354605' 
                        GROUP  BY EP_101.CD_HFDMAPNR)T2 
                    ON T1.DOSSIERNUMMER = T2.DOSSIERNUMMER
```

Comment: what way to go anway? 2 first sql query filters on bkcode 000010 and the other one on 000020 so those to are diffirent and will give 2 totally diffirent results, how is the way the go then?